# Как я могу использовать SetActive после определенной анимации в Unity

Tags: unity3d, 2d

в игре которую я делаю объект должен появится после того как определенная анимация закончиться. Я пробовал в State Machine Behaviour и через switch, но у меня ничего не получилось. Есть ли какой-то более действующий метод?

Comment: Что-то сделал не так, но по описанию непонятно, что ты делал. Если надо что-то простое, а анимация идет фиксированное время, сделай перед стартом анимации Invoke c задержкой https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html

Comment: Спасибо большое. Это было именно то что я искал!

Comment: Оформил как ответ

Answer (score 0):

Если нужен простой способ, а анимация идет фиксированное время, можно сделать перед стартом анимации Invoke c задержкой, см. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html